# What is trauma literature?

Tags: terminology, genre

I recently stumbled upon the term "trauma literature". However, I am having a hard time figuring out what it actually refers to. There is almost no piece of literature that does not contain an element of trauma.

What does this term mean?

Comment: Welcome to Literature Stack Exchange, take our [tour]! Where did you find this term? In a book, on a website, in a conversation with a librarian, etc.?

Answer (score 3):

It's certainly true that trauma and traumatic events feature in many works of literature.

However, Trauma Literature focuses on trauma as a central theme, and often on the difficulty of expressing that trauma through the literary medium.

The literary work itself often becomes an expression of a traumatic reaction. For example, in the graphic novel Maus, the author Art Spiegelman replaces human characters with animals. This allows him to deal with a modified (and thus less threatening) variation of the traumatic reality.

Thus the trauma in the novel is not just one limited aspect, but arguably **the entire work** is an expression of trauma and a defensive reaction related to that trauma.

Comment: Do you have any references for this answer?

Comment: @bobble there is this article: https://lithub.com/what-i-teach-seven-titles-from-a-high-school-class-on-trauma-literature which also mentions the example I gave, Maus.